# Facebook's all.js not compatible with $.getScript()

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to include Facebook's Javascript SDK (the all.js file from http://connect.facebook.com/en_US/all.js) dynamically vis javascript for my web app. I have used the following code.

```
$.getScript('http://connect.facebook.com/en_US/all.js', function() {
  alert('Facebook script has loaded');
});
```

When this is executed, currently I find that the page never alerts. My main aim is to load the Facebook JS SDK programatically. Kindly let me know if there is something wrong in what I am doing or is there any other way to achieve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The url is wrong, change to:

```
'http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'
```

Also see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/FS3hR/).